# How to recover files from infected. Vvv extention

Tags: windows, filesystems, encryption, public-key-encryption, anti-malware

Can any one help for how can remove this virus. Our all computer's files infected from this (.vvv) virus. We are using windows 7 Plz give me strong methods. If you need remote screen i will provide you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a link from google on how to remove TeslaCrypt. The crypted files are lost though. https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/8724-teslacrypt-virus

Comment: TeslaCrypt has been decoded in the meantime: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/576600/tesladecoder-released-to-decrypt-exx-ezz-ecc-files-encrypted-by-teslacrypt/

Answer (score 1):

vvv extensions - most likely the telsacrypt virus.  If this is the case, then you need to know the private key to decrypt your files.  This means you either pay the ransom and get the key (but odds are they will take your money and give you the wrong key to try and get you to pay again and again) - or you need to format your hard drive and restore your files from a backup.

If I am wrong and this isn't telsacrypt - then you need to reboot your computer into safe mode, download and run a whole bunch of different cleaners (not every cleaner catches everything) and then backup your files and wipe your disk.  Some good free anti-virus/malware/spyware titles include [AVG](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/homepage), [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-gb/index), [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus), [adaware](http://www.lavasoft.com/), [spybot S&D](https://www.safer-networking.org/), the list is long, so search the net and see what you find.

While you can remove TelsaCrypt, you can never be 100% confident that your machine is properly clean after removal, so a format is advisible.

The link in the comments (helpfully posted by Moh-aw): [pcrisk.com/removal-guides/8724-teslacrypt-virus](http://pcrisk.com/removal-guides/8724-teslacrypt-virus)
 seems to be very comprehensive for removing the virus (although I have never had to do this myself) - however, as stated - you will lose all your infected files.